# iOS URL Scheme: Online giving completion redirection challenge

Tags: ios

We have an iOS native app, that allows for online giving for churches through a external web page. The native app opens the browser, and the once the user is done with their online giving on the web page it uses a URL scheme to return back to the native app.

This works great, but isn't ideal because when the user later returns to their web browser they see the remnant of the external web page.

Currently we just do some JavaScript and clean up the page so to speak to avoid duplicate gifts etc. Is there a way we can redirect the page to the users default page, or home page?

Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you present an inline UIWebView? Then you can just remove it.

Comment: @H2CO3 You aren't allowed to do that for donations, they may only be done through Safari or SMS.

Comment: I think this is more a web question than iOS. I don't know any native functionality to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle your online gift in an internal [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which would give you much more control over this aspect of your application.

Comment: You aren't allowed to do that for donations, they may only be done through Safari or SMS. Section 21.2 of the App Store Review Guidelines.